# Python - Expand values of a third column after splitting column

Tags: python, pandas

My DF looks like this:

[image]

I know how to split the column 'value' in two columns: gender_age and total:

```
es = pd.DataFrame([{'gender_age' : key, 'total' : value } for d in df_hist_data['value'].tolist() for key, value in d.items()])
```

which gives me this:

[image]

My problem is the column 'end_time'...
If I try to simply concatenate both DFs:

```
rr = pd.concat([df_hist_data.drop('value', axis=1), es], axis=1)
```

gives me this - NaN instead of the dates:

[image]

Please, could you help me to expand also the values of the column end_time?
Thanks

Comment: Take a close look at `df_hist_data` and `es` dataframe. The former has 84 rows, and the latter has 1259 rows. These two are not in the same shape of rows to be appended to each other.

Comment: How do you see your end result in this case?

Comment: Kiani I know that.. Thanks! What I need is that when the dataframe is expanded to 1259 rows, the values of the column 'end_time' need to 'repeat' accordingly and do not return NaN... I am struggling with that.

Comment: Vishal Kamlapure the values of 'end_time' also expanded, repeating the values accordingly...

Comment: I don't know why my question was marked as duplicated. My question has not been answered in the question they say it is duplicate...